# Updating twitter oAuth tokens when expired

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, token

I have an oAuth `access_token` and `secret_key` linked to one account id stored in my DB, and for example, a twitter user changes his password of his twitter account.

As far I know about oAuth, `access_token` and `secret_key` for this user are going to be generated again. How can I update tokens for this user id in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the user changing his password should have any affect on the access token or secret. In OAuth 1.0a an access token is valid until a user revokes access to the application.